# HTML5 input pattern backslash character

Tags: html

I need to have a HTML5 input with a pattern that allows to insert any number of capital letters, numbers and/or "\" characters. How should I change the code:

```
pattern="[\\A-Z0-9]"
```

Comment: You should not rely on this. It's probably better to go with JavaScript.

Comment: Why should I not relay on HTML 5 pattern?

Comment: Never mind my comment, browser support seems to be ok now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RegEx needs to match the entire input:

```html
<form onsubmit='alert("Submitted")'>
  <input type='text' pattern='[\\A-Z0-9]*' />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern)

Comment: I see my mistake now. Thank you